# Using both unicode-math and mathabx fails with "Command \circ, \diamond, \bullet, ... already defined"

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, incompatibility, mathabx

In my document I need `unicode-math` at some point to conveniently use Unicode characters in my source files and `mathabx` for the `\Vdash` macro (a variant of `\vdash`).
It seems these packages are incompatible with one another: the MWE below fails compilation with XeLaTeX.

Does anyone have an idea how I can resolve this?

```tex
% !TEX TS-program = latexmk -xelatex -f %
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

```
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/mathabx/mathabx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/mathabx/mathabx.dcl

! LaTeX Error: Command `\circ' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.36 ...MathSymbol{\circ}          {2}{matha}{"05}

?

! LaTeX Error: Command `\diamond' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.45 ...MathSymbol{\diamond}       {2}{matha}{"0C}

?

! LaTeX Error: Command `\bullet' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.46 ...MathSymbol{\bullet}        {2}{matha}{"0D}

?

! LaTeX Error: Command `\emptyset' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.288 ...athSymbol{\emptyset}      {0}{matha}{"48}

?

! LaTeX Error: Command `\owns' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.300 ...athSymbol{\owns}          {3}{matha}{"51}
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the packages with different order?

Comment: The `\Vdash` character is `"2C`, so applying the code from the duplicate would be `\DeclareMathSymbol{\Vdash}{3}{matha}{"2C}`.

Comment: `unicode-math` already has `\Vdash`, for U+22A9 (⊩). Are you sure you need `mathabx`? You could use another font’s glyph with `\setmathfont[range=\Vdash, Scale=MatchUppercase]{...}`.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to make `mathabx` and `unicode-math` to coexist. Why loading both?